# How to make sure not to call http module from particular file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an website under which i have 5  files

1. test1.aspx
2. test2.aspx
3. test3.aspx
4. test4.aspx
5. test5.aspx

i have an http module which gets called in all the pages
but i have an condition where on test5.aspx page i do not want the http module  to be called what settings need  to be  done in order to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 7):

HttpModules get run before your page lifecycle, so you'd have to match it on the request path.

Assuming your HttpModule's `Init` function sets up a `BeforeRequest` handler, something like:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += this.BeginRequest;
    }

    public void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app.Request.Path.Contains("test5.aspx")) {
            return;
        }

        // Process logic for other pages here
    }
}
```